# What is the meaning of the opening scene in Citizen Kane?

Tags: citizen-kane

In the opening scene of Citizen Kane, there are phantasmagoric scenes showing monkeys and in another a statue of a cat and in another a sort of ancient pyramid. What is the meaning of these strange landscapes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images are of Kane's estate in Florida, called Xanadu, where we see his dying moment.  Described in the newsreel in the movie as being "The world's largest private pleasureground", containing a private zoo, museums of art works, golf course, gondolas as well as his home.

Not sure what 'meaning' can be ascribed to these images, other than it shows the ridiculous wealth and isolation of Kane, behind his fence with the 'No Tresspassing' sign and the estate being unfinished and falling in to disrepair.